# Android call makePayment how

Tags: java, android, payment

i want to call `makePayment();` I want to automatically run ......
This is my code

```
package com.musicdownloader;


import com.fortumo.android.PaymentActivity;
import com.musicdownloader.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class app extends PaymentActivity {

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           makePayment();    
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.main);

               Button payButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
               payButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                           final EditText q = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.q);
                            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/search?q=" +q.getText().toString()));
                            startActivity(i);

                       }
               });

       }
       @Override
       protected void onPaymentCanceled(String product) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Payment canceled by user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPaymentFailed(String product) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Payment failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPaymentPending(long messageId, String product) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Payment not confirmed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPaymentSuccess(String product) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Payment received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

How to call it??
Thank you

Comment: btW: it's good practice to usually call the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); first, then your own custom stuff. You're already calling makePayment() in your onCreate - where exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mathias, actually, in Android, it's not just good practice, it's required.  I'm pretty sure it'll blow up if you don't call it first...

Answer (score 1):

You should call it in your `onStart` method, *after* you called `super.onStart`.